# Override abstract field in child classes

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, inheritance

In C#, is it possible to have an abstract parent class that declares a field of a type that itself corresponds to an abstract class and must be overridden in the child classes?

Here's the idea:

```cs
public abstract class AbstractInfo {
    // ...
    public GameplayResult gameplayResult;
}

public class LevelInfo : AbstractInfo {
    // ...
    public LevelGameplayResult gameplayResult;
}

public class BossInfo : AbstractInfo {
    // ...
    public BossGameplayResult gameplayResult;
}
```

With:

```cs
public abstract class GameplayResult {
    // ...
}

public class LevelGameplayResult : GameplayResult {
    // ...
}

public class BossGameplayResult : GameplayResult {
    // ...
}
```

The goal is to be able to have another class:

```cs
public class Manager {
    // ...    

    public AbstractInfo info;

    public void UpdateInfo(GameplayResult gameplayResult) {
        info.gameplayResult = gameplayResult;
        // Where info could be a level info or boss info
        // and gameplay result could be a level or boss gameplay result    
    }
}
```

Comment: You can have abstract properties in C#: public abstract GameplayResult gameplayResult { get; }

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of issues in the example you've given.

1. Although it isn't invalid, currently, your derived classes are hiding the base class's member `gameplayResult` and thus redeclaring them. If you're looking for overriding a member, you need to use the `override` keyword in the derived class and make the member `abstract` or `virtual` in the base class. Furthermore, a member field cannot be abstract, but you can use a property instead:

```
public abstract class AbstractInfo
{
    public abstract GameplayResult GameplayResult { get; set; }
}

public class LevelInfo : AbstractInfo
{
    // Still something wrong here (see #2)
    public override LevelGameplayResult GameplayResult { get; set; }
    // For later demonstration...
    public bool IAmLevelInfo { get; } = true;
}
```

2. You cannot change the type of an overridden member.

Consider the example:

```
public void DoSomethingWithInfo(AbstractInfo info)
{
    info.GameplayResult = new BossGameplayResult();
}

var lvlInf = new LevelInfo();

// Some time later...

DoSomethingWithInfo(lvlInfo);

if (!lvlInfo.IAmLevelInfo)
{
    Console.WriteLine("How did this happen o.O")?
}
```

In the above example it should be completely legal to call `DoSomethingWithInfo(lvlInfo)` because `LevelInfo` is also an `AbstractInfo`. Inside the method we're trying to assign a `BossGameplayResult` to an `AbstractInfo`'s `GameplayResult` which is completely legal. However, we passed in a `LevelInfo` which does not allow you to assign a `BossGameplayResult` to `GameplayResult`. So we've hit a paradox. Of course, the above won't even compile, because the compiler is clever enough to realize this.

To solve this issue, you can use [generics](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/fundamentals/types/generics):

```
public abstract class AbstractInfo<T> where T : GameplayResult
{
    public T GameplayResult { get; set; }
}

public class LevelInfo : AbstractInfo<LevelGameplayResult>
{
    // No need for overriding, as 'GameplayResult' will
    // have type 'LevelGameplayResult'
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I am trying out your generics approach! However, this causes issues in my `Manager` class. Namely, if I change the declaration of the field from `public AbstractInfo info;` to `public AbstractInfo<GameplayResult> info;` then I can no longer assign it using `info = new LevelInfo();`. The error is "CS0029: Cannot implicitly convert type... LevelInfo... to ... AbstractInfo<GameplayResult>...".

Comment: And if I try `info = new LevelInfo<LevelGameplayResult>();` instead, then I get the error "CS0308: The non-generic type LevelInfo cannot be used with type arguments."

Comment: To clarify my goal, I am looking to have a `Manager` class with an `info` field that (at runtime) can store either a LevelInfo or a BossInfo instance. Also, for context, I don't just have those two info types, I actually have six.

Comment: @Ben ok, but do you actually need to know if the type of the property `GameplayResult` is a `LevelGameplayResult` or `BossGameplayResult`? If not, there's no need for "overriding" the property or making it generic. If you do, can you show the scenario you need it for?